# JQuery syntax issue - using 'this' and checking CSS attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Jquery function that works fine as it is on an old website.  When moving some of the contents to a new website the function no longer works and I cannot figure out why this is.

```
 <div class="hr-banner noselect"><img draggable="false" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/people-development.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <p class="hr-banner-title">People Development</p>

    <div class="hr-banner-text">

    As an employer, we understand the value of investing in the skills and knowledge of our employees, allowing

    them to develop and achieve their own professional goals.

    </div>
<div class="hr-banner noselect"><img draggable="false" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/people-development.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <p class="hr-banner-title">People Development</p>

    <div class="hr-banner-text">

    As an employer, we understand the value of investing in the skills and knowledge of our employees, allowing

    them to develop and achieve their own professional goals.

    </div>


$(".hr-banner").click(function(evt) {

    var shouldShow = $(".hr-banner-text", this).css("display") == "none";
    console.log(shouldShow);
        $(".hr-banner-title", this).hide();
        $(".hr-banner-text", this).show();
    if (shouldShow) {
        $(".hr-banner-title", this).hide();
        $(".hr-banner-text", this).show();
        console.log("should show");
    } else {
        $(".hr-banner-title", this).show();
        $(".hr-banner-text", this).hide();
        console.log("no show");
    }
});
```

I have set up a JS fiddle and it doesn't work there either, so Ive no idea how its working on the old site!

The line:

```
var shouldShow = $(".hr-banner-text", this).css("display") == "none";
```

Always returns false, even though the **display:none** is set in the CSS for the **.hr-banner-text**
When I try manually setting **var shouldShow** to true, the hide() and show() functions still do not work.  I think the syntax is wrong and 'this' isn't correct I but dont know how to fix.

Can anyone help me get this working?  Im not great with JQuery syntax.

Comment: Can we see your jsfiddle?

Comment: oops, sorry, missed adding that!  Added now, thanks.

Comment: The code, markup, and CSS for your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. External links rot, and separately people shouldn't have to go offsite to understand your question. Ideally, put an [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".hr-banner-text", this)` will search for the element `.hr-banner-text` inside the current(*this*) element.

As, the element `.hr-banner-text` is not nested in the `.hr-banner` element, no element will be selected.

You need to use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Also, instead of `.css('display')`, I'll suggest to use `.is(':visible')` or `is(':hidden')` to check the element's visibility.

```
var shouldShow = $(this).siblings('.hr-banner-text').is(":hidden");
```

Looking at the commented code in the fiddle, you're trying to toggle the elements based on the visibility of the element. You can use [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

---

After wrapping the elements in `.hr-banner`

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6rk05wny/1/)

```js
$(".hr-banner").click(function() {
    $(".hr-banner-title, .hr-banner-text").toggle();
});
```

```css
.hr-banner {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hr-banner > img {
    width: 98%;
}

.hr-banner-title {
    margin: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin-top: -3em;
    margin-left: 16px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hr-banner-text {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 98%;
    height: 100%;
}

.hr-noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hr-banner noselect"><img draggable="false" src="https://daisygroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/people-development.jpg" alt="" />
    <p class="hr-banner-title">People Development</p>

    <div class="hr-banner-text">

        As an employer, we understand the value of investing in the skills and knowledge of our employees, allowing them to develop and achieve their own professional goals.

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats great, but it doesn't work for multiple elements, sorry I didnt add multipe to the JS fiddle, I assumed my mentioning the use of "this" was enough